# FindConnectionPoint , what parameters to pass

Tags: c++, com

I am trying to subscribe to an event to a COM library and am stuck at `FindConnectionPoint`. I am using C++ VS2010 and am following this [article][1] which states

> IConnectionPointContainer::FindConnectionPoint, using the GUID that
>   represents the desired interface.

Now what is suppose to be the first parameter of this method is it suppose to be a guid no like uuid(192B9F3E-DF39-41A5-95E0-0333B061CAB8) ? I only have the tlb file and am using oleview to explore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the Interface Identifier (IID), so something like this:

```
point_container->FindConnectionPoint(IID__ISTIEventsEvents ,&conn_point);
```

If you don't have defined in a header file, you can create it using [the #import "mytlb.tlb"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) directive, or just create it manually anywhere in your code using the 192B9F3E-DF39-41A5-95E0-0333B061CAB8 value.

Comment: yes, if you have _ISTIEventsEvents defined with an uuid and all that, but I thought you only had a TLB